# Increase gap between lines is dropdown

Tags: asp.net, dropdownbox

I have a asp:dropdown....

Populated from a sql DB... There are quite a few options so I want to create a small gap say 10px between each of the lines...

Heres the DD Code

```
<td class="whiteCell" style="color:black">
Select a standard phrase to use in the comments section below:
<br />
<asp:DropDownList CssClass="whiteCell_DDP" ID="ddlPhrases" Width="600" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlPhrase_changed" runat="server" />
</td>
```

Then is the cs file...

```
// get the print phrases
var ph = from i in data.PRINTPHRASEs orderby i.PrintPhraseID ascending select i;

foreach (PRINTPHRASE p in ph)
{
string txt = p.PrintPhraseID.ToString() + ": " + p.Body;
ddlPhrases.Items.Add(new ListItem(txt, p.PrintPhraseID.ToString()));
}
```

It works well and I', propbably missing something obvious..

Thanks

Andrew

Comment: Shouldn't "CssClass" just be "class"? I would apply a CSS style to it of "padding-bottom:10px;"

Comment: Your code is for ASP.NET, not asp-classic as specified

Comment: Thank you Gary, I've changed the tag..